# Independence of two discrete random variables and their support.

Tags: statistics

I know that two discrete random variables, $X$ and $Y$, are independent if $P(X = x, Y = y) = P(X = x)\cdot P(Y = y)$. I also know that if the underlying space, $S$, of their joint pmf is non-rectangular that they are necessarily dependent. However are they necessarily independent if their underlying space $S$ is rectangular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is NO.  Easy examples will show that. Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables, each of which takes on only the two possible values zero and one.  Then the outcome space is a "rectanlge", that is, a (Cartesian) product $ \{0,1\} \times \{0,1\}$.  Then specify the following distribution, through a table of probabilities:

```
                          X
                0                    1   
  Y    0       0.1                  0.3
       1       0.3                  0.3
```

The body of the table containing the probabilities.  You can check $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.